# Appcelerator Titanium Alloy: How to set the TableViewStyle to GROUPED in xml

Tags: titanium, tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I've tried various things along the lines of (also tried just setting style to GROUPED):

```
<Alloy>
    <Window title="Add Remember">
        <TableView id="table" style="Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED">
        <!-->
            <TableViewSection headerTitle="Title">
                <TableViewRow><TextField hintText="Title" id="title"></TextField></TableViewRow>
            </TableViewSection>

            <TableViewSection headerTitle="Location">
                <TableViewRow><TextField hintText="Location" id="location"></TextField></TableViewRow>
            </TableViewSection>

            <TableViewSection headerTitle="Notes">
                <TableViewRow><TextArea hintText="Notes"></TextArea></TableViewRow>
            </TableViewSection>
        </!-->
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

But no shebang.

I've also noticed that setting it programmatically in the controller file works, but only if I haven't added any sections or rows to the TableView yet (this is why the sections and rows are commented out above).

How do I set this property in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it this way:

In `form.xml`:

```
<TableView class="form">
  ...
</TableView>
```

In `app.tss`:

```
".form": {
  style: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is to set `style="1"` in the xml for the TableView; this works with the sections and rows uncommented as well. I figured this out by logging `Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED` to the console; evidently the macro doesn't work in the xml.

Comment: I suspect this is a namespace issue. I would also recommend logging these issues directly to the alloy user group when JIRAs can be created when necessary